# Combining coordinates from two columns into one

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the distance of point A to point B, but the coordinates are spread out into 4 columns.

```
Point_a_lat  Point_a-long  Point_b_lat  Point_B_long
-----------------------------------------------------
 40.744607   -73.990742     40.752073   -73.985370
```

Since Geopy.distance can't calculate the distance with the coordinates spread out into four columns, my best guess is to simply combine point a's lat and lon and likewise for point b.

I thought it would be easier but I'm having trouble.

I tried turning them into a list

```
df['point_a'] = list(zip(df.Point_a_lat, df.Point_a_lon))
df['point_b'] = list(zip(df.Point_b_lat, df.Point_b_lon))
```

but it won't accept that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I guess that got cut off. Let me edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need call function `vincenty` by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processes per rows:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: vincenty((x['Point_a_lat'], x['Point_a_lon']), 
                                             (x['Point_b_lat'], x['Point_b_lon'])).m, axis=1)
print (df)

   Point_a_lat  Point_a_lon  Point_b_lat  Point_b_lon    distance
0    40.744607   -73.990742    40.752073    -73.98537  945.107136
```